# Imported Pillow But I Still Get "No Module Named PIL"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm using python3 and I ran `conda install pillow`. When I run `conda list` I can see that it is installed. In my jupyter notebook, however, I am getting the following error:

> ---> 10 from PIL import Image
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

I saw other posts on StackOverflow that said to use `pip install pillow` instead. I tried that but had the same results. Any help is appreciated! Thanks~

Comment: When you do `pip list` does it show something like Pillow (x.x.x)?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed?

Comment: JohnDoe - when I run `pip list` I get Pillow (4.2.1)

Comment: skrx - I actually tried this with 2 different conda environments. One has both python 2 and 3. The other just has just python 3.

Comment: Double check if you're installing and importing it with the same Python version.

Comment: @skrx - how do I check this? I'm using anaconda...shouldn't that make sure it's importing with the correct version?

Comment: I'm not familiar with anaconda, so you should search on your own. Once someone had a similar problem and it turned out that he installed the package with anaconda and then tried to import it with the normal (non-anaconda) Python or vice-versa. To see your Python version, open the shell and enter `import sys; sys.version`. And in the command-line/terminal enter `conda --version` and also `conda list` to see which packages are installed.

Comment: @skrx  it's the same version of python. Like I said in the original post, I also tried uninstalled it with `conda uninstall` and then using `pip install pillow` That didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while back but forgot to come back to the question. Running `conda install ipykernel nb_conda_kernels` worked like a charm.

Comment: Is this for running `tkinter` in notebooks?